# Change X11 dpi on the fly on NixOS

Tags: x11, xrandr, nixos

I expect `xrandr --dpi 180` to change the dpi from 90 to 180 on the fly per-session and thus downscale resolution, but nothing happens. Am I missing something? I was able to change the dpi with the silly hack of adding `fonts.fontconfig.dpi=180` to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` then `nixos-rebuild test`, which is less than ideal.

To be very clear, here's my situation: 
1. the default resolution is too low for my laptop screen and everything (fonts) looks painfully small. 
2. I learned adding `fonts.fontconfig.dpi=180` to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` on nixos can set the dpi to 180 from the default 96 so that everything has normal size (fonts). 
3. However, I now sometimes open the vm on a monitor which has lower resolution than my laptop, and I'd like to change the dpi on the fly when switching between using the laptop screen and the monitor.

Comment: How is your monitor connected? With DisplayPort you can not change resolution, and can not change DPI on the fly.

Comment: Rather than reposting your question from SO, you should have asked a moderator to migrate it ;)

Comment: @BarafuAlbino It's shown as VGA-0 in virtualbox and the physical connection is mini display port dongled to HDMI. I was able to do `xrandr --output VGA-0 --scale 2x2` to scale down everything, but that has the strange bug of partially freezing X11...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting custom DPI in xfce4-appearance-settings always seemed to work fine for me. I've never tried another way.

Comment: Any idea how xfce handles it? I'm using xmonad

Comment: Incidentally, I use xmonad in an xfce session. IIRC for some X changes to apply "as one expects", one needs a daemon - in Xfce this is filled by xfsettingsd.